# Android GoogleCloudMessaging.register() returns SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE after app re-install

Tags: android, google-api, google-cloud-messaging

Working on a Google Cloud Messaging-enabled App for a class.  I had "round-trip" (App->backend server, backend server->GCM->App) working on both my phone and tablet.  After getting things stable, I uninstalled the App on the phone (mainly to trash the database that I'd filled with bogus entries) and then re-installed.  However now, when the app attempts to re-register with GoogleCloudMessaging, it kicks back "SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE."  I had run into this a couple days ago, but it seems like after waiting a couple of minutes, it'd be able to register.  I figured it was something on Google's end needing to update.  However I've let my phone sit for almost 12 hours now and it still is unable to get a new registration ID.

Is there something more required to get a new registration ID than a call to register()?  I've tried calling unregister() as well, thinking that maybe GCM needed a "hint" that the phone needed a new registration ID and that the old one was invalid, but that also kicked back SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE.  As a side note, the tablet (which has a registration ID) continues to work fine.  Messages are being received from GCM.  I just get nothing on the phone.

Other info:  This is using the HTTP (downstream only) GCM configuration, Phone is API 17, Tablet is API 19.  Play services are up-to-date.  The implementation I used for the receiver and registration is "pretty close" to what Google provided as their example.

Comment: I have the same problem with Nexus 4